# What is the story of Akshaya Patra? How is this related to Akshaya Tritiya?

Tags: mahabharata, history, festivals

Is Akshaya Patra mentioned in the *Mahabharata*? If so, what is the story?

*Paramahansa Yogananda*, is his book [Autobiography of A Yogi](http://www.vsc.iitm.ac.in/Home/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Yogananda-Autobiography.pdf) , narrates a similar incident

> ...“As soon as each man had expressed his preferences, the FAKIR
>   addressed himself to the inexhaustible Hazrat. A great rattle ensued;
>   gold platters filled with intricately−prepared curries, hot LUCHIS,
>   and many out−of−season fruits, landed from nowhere at our feet. All
>   the food was delicious. After feasting for an hour, we started to
>   leave the room. A tremendous noise, as though dishes were being piled
>   up, caused us to turn around. Lo! there was no sign of the glittering
>   plates or the remnants of the meal.”...

Also, is it related to *Akshaya Tritiya?* If so, what is the connection?

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/how-is-akshaya-tritiya-celebrated) question discusses various possible reasons behind the festival of Askhaya Tritiya without any mention to the Akshaya Patra.

Comment: According to Skanda Purana, the 3rd day of bright half  of Vaishaka (named as Akshaya) is liked by Vishnu. So, it is called Akshaya Trutiya and i think it has no connection with Akshaya Patra.

Comment: HI Here is the Exact Story of Akshya Patra. Click This Link and Enjoy :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgVUWX36Lf0

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03003.htm) is the story mentioned in Mahabharata

> And Vivaswan said, 'Thou shall obtain all that thou desirest. I shall provide thee with food for five and seven years together. And, O king, accept this copper-vessel which I give unto thee. And, O thou of excellent vows, as long as Panchali will hold this vessel, without partaking of its contents fruits and roots and meat and vegetables cooked in thy kitchen, these four kinds of food shall from this day be inexhaustible. And, on the fourteenth year from this, thou shall regain thy kingdom.'

I didn't find any reference for the relationship between Akshaya Patra and Akshaya Tritiya but [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akshaya_Tritiya) in the Wikipedia it is mentioned.

In Mahabharata, Yudhishthira receives the Akshaya patra, which he uses to serve food for all the needy in his kingdom.

Comment: Who is Vivaswan? Ya, I am aware of the wiki reference, thats where this question is inspired from :)

Comment: Vivaswan is Sun

Comment: They used the Akshaya Patra during the exile. He uses it to serve food for his family and the sages who visited him.